# Solving a pure function to obtain function definition and then map that function

Tags: equation-solving, pure-function

I've been trying to use *Solve* with pure functions to receive function definition and then use it with *Map* , to obtain results from mapping function to some data.

Here is an example

```
(#2 /. Solve[25 == #1^2 + #2^2, #2]) //circle equation
```

When I run this, I receive "function" definition

```
out1 = {-Sqrt[25 - #1^2], Sqrt[25 - #1^2]}
```

If I add & in the end of out1, and then Map this function to some data, I obtain what I need.

```
{-Sqrt[25 - #1^2], Sqrt[25 - #1^2]} & /@ Range[1, 10, 1]
```

Now I'm trying done this in one step:

```
 (#2 /. Solve[25 == #1^2 + #2^2, #2])&/@Range[1,10,1]
```

But I see that it isn't working, I see this is because added ampersand.

And here is another example

```
(y /. Solve[#1 x + #2 y + #3 == 0, y] &)[3, 4, 5]
```

it produces:

```
out2= {1/4 (-5 - 3 x)}
```

OK, now I want to treat with this like a function and x as variable.
I can do something like that:

```
   {1/4 (-5 - 3 #1)} &
```

And it will work, I can Map it, but it isn't what I wish.

Trying to do it in one step:

```
(y /. Solve[#1 *#4 + #2 y + #3 == 0, y] &)[3, 4, 5] & // #4 is x
```

I can't get what I want in one step.

Can anyone show how to do it?

Comment: I don't understand what your question is ...

Comment: Please don´t use `//` (`Postfix`) for comments. This is used for postfix notation. Use `(* ... *)` instead.

Comment: Please reformulate the question a bit more concisely, like this: "I tried *this* code.  I expected *this* output. I got *that* output instead."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possibly this can be made more elegant but forcing Evaluation and applying Function can achieve what you want I think along these lines...

```
Function@Evaluate[(#2 /. Solve[25 == #1^2 + #2^2, #2])] /@  Range[1, 10, 1]
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! Evaluate make kerned to eval Solve and replace, and then use map.
It also works with second example, But Evaluate do not need in this case.
(x~Function~(y /. Solve[#1 *x + #2 y + #3 == 0, y] &[3, 4, 5])) /@ 
 Range[1, 10, 1]

Answer (score 3):

This achieves the same as the answer from Ymareth, but uses a different way:

```
With[{f = (#2 /. Solve[25 == #1^2 + #2^2, #2])}, f & /@ Range[1, 10, 1]]
```

It first runs `Solve` and then inserts the result as the function body to be used in the `Map`.

I'd say it's a matter of taste which to use.

Comment: Thanks, it's too interesting way to solve my problem.